# Django Awaiting Appoval

Tags: django

If you want user to submit say articles to your website but you want to approve these articles before they are added to a list of articles, how would you go about doing so?

The only method I can think of is to have 2 databases; one for 'awaiting approval' and another for 'approved and ready to be displayed'. However, my issue is whether there is a fast method to go about transferring the information between the two databases? I only know about doing this manually.

Or is there already a Django module that handles this?

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jordi has said, add an extra field, but you might also want to write a custom manager for your table that selects posts according to status.

See the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/ where they set up a manager that filters on sex="M" to only return Male people. This makes your code neater, and means as long as you go through the right manager you'll not have to keep remembering to test for state="Approved" all the time.

If you want to get more complex, the thing you are doing is called "Workflow" and there are django and python packages that implement this - but it gets very complex very quickly...

Answer (score 2):

Just add a column to the database table called status

1 = waiting
2 = approved
3 = denied